# date filter of today in rest api

Tags: list, caml-query, filter, date-time, rest

I have a caml query filter for one of my date-time field.

```
<Leq>
  <FieldRef Name ='StartDate1' />
  <Value Type ='DateTime'>
    <Today />
  </Value>
</Leq>
```

Is there anything same for rest api filter also?

```
StartDate1 leq ?
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the date value like `EndTime le datetime'2013-06-12'`
Note: You may need to use `ListData.svc` if you are on SP 2013.

> I started with turning on Team Collaboration Lists feature on my
>   publishing site and creating the Calendar list. Then I have got my
>   REST endpoint, this time around with a "greater than or equal to"
>   filter:
>
> `http://devserver2012/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('events')/items?$select=Id,Title,Description,EventDate,EndDate,fAllDayEvent&$filter=EventDate ge datetime'2013-06-08T00:00:00'`   The reason for my blog post is that
>   the above RESTful call doesn't work. Research has pointed out a few
>   things:  I am not the only one. Other people have had the issue. Rob
>   Windsor's comment was quite useful to me. The MSDN guidance has a
>   table of supported filtering operations. First of all, it incorrectly
>   capitalizes the numeric comparison operations. For example, instead of
>   "Ge" operator which does not work, I was using "ge" which does work.
>   Second of all, the references pointing back at www.odata.org were
>   unfortunately broken there, at the time of this writing at least.
>   Later I've learned that my filter actually works with a Boolean "and"
>   operator as I will show below. Does this make it unsupported? It
>   probably does, according to the mentioned MSDN article, although the
>   article itself clearly needs a revision. OData documentation is your
>   friend. I find it hard to read, yet it is ultimately helpful. You can
>   see query options supported by OData in section 4.5 on this page.
>   Notice how the operators are all lowercase in the examples.  The
>   formatting of dates in filter queries can be found here. This is where
>   the datetime'2013-06-08T00:00:00' comes from. One interesting detail,
>   although the format spec does not indicate this, the following works
>   just as well: datetime'2013-06-08T00:00:00Z'. Apparently the ISO-8601
>   is still honored. Getting back to my original REST call - what "fixes"
>   it? If I were to use ListData.svc instead then I'd get the following:

```
http://devserver2012/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/Events?$select=Id,Title,StartTime,EndTime,AllDayEvent&$filter=StartTime
> ge datetime'2013-06-10' and EndTime lt datetime'2013-06-12'
```

Reference: http://neganov.blogspot.in/2013/06/filtering-items-by-date-range-using.html